# jQuery approach instead of full MVC framework

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently building a frontend architecture for quite a big site (9 digit monthly pageviews). One of the requirements is ability to fast changes as the businessfield changes, so I'd want to keep everything as lean as possible and thus am pondering about forgoing full-on MCV framework and just using jQuery (plugins) instead.

Here's how it would work:

First pageview, server renders the full page (in order to support crawling) - Loads data, renders it into template (mustache) and that into layout.

If history API is enabled, then next pageviews will be rendered with Javascript (data+mustache template), no hashrouting here (due crawlers). If not, then everything will be rendered serverside.

So, as clientside routing basically won't be needed at all, full-on MVC framework seems like a overkill.

So, here's what I'm thinking - Just do the data-loading & rendering as jQuery plugin. I'm currently even thinking about forgoing databinding as well, as the site is more about content than complex functionality, which would simplify the structure even more. Data changes could just be handled with re-rendering the content.

What kind of pitfalls does this approach have in such scale?

Answer (score 0):

There are two general approaches:

First one - If your main requirement is `ability to fast changes as the businessfield changes` using an MVC framework might spare you a lot of grief in as using one of those leads to much cleaner and easier to maintain and extend code, even if you don't use all of its features, i. e. routing. **Backbone** is a good choice, if you're looking for a simple lightweight framework. On the contrary, when things start to become more and more complex, managing a growing jQuery application becomes increasingly harder, in comparison to backbone, angular, etc.

Second one - is stated in a nice abbreviation of YAGNI - You Ain't Gonna Need It. If you're certain you won't be delving in some complex frontend features, that requires data bindings, event composition, routing etc. in the forseeable future - why even bother considering MVC frontend framework? They are designed mainly to simplify creation of complex frontend applications, not to make simple things more complex. If all you ever gonna need is load server-side data and pass it to a template - then you might not even need jQuery for this, and do just fine with pure JavaScript.

So after all it's up to you to decide, does the complexity of your project call for more advanced tools, or you'd be fine with simple ones.

Comment: Of course one can't know for sure if something complex is needed in future, however now it's only mainly content creation & consumption site (think of Quora). One of the problems with clientside frameworks is that they aren't crawlable - a must as lots of content aimed towards Google et al. The only solution that I know of, that can be used on both rendering on clientside and serverside is mustache, which from the established libraries is only used by Ember (200+kB). However, going full-on mobile first I'm bit concerned of bringing Ember-sized libraries to the mix just for rendering.

Comment: Yes, Ember is quite large, and, judging by tests, isn't too fast either, especially on mobile devices. Then, as i already said, i don't see why you bother considering frontend MVC framework at all. If you don't want all them advanced features, building a content-based site wouldn't be too hard with jQuery alone.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm considering at the moment. :) I'm just trying to cover all the bases and trying to think, what would be the potential potholes with this approach. Fe. in the future, more complex functionality is needed. Currently I'm thinking of each template being in their own .hbs file and having their own .js file for functionality (loaded on-demand), to reduce the potential JS bloat. Any critical problems with that approach when the request comes for more advanced functionality? Or other approaches to consider?

Comment: Hard to tell. Practically, MVC frameworks aren't bringing any new functionality by themselves. 'More advanced functionality' usually means more advanced UI. Lots of events, states, publishers and subscribers everywhere... this kind of stuff. Here jQuery folds outright, your code becomes eldritch horror real quick OR you just end up writing your own AngularJS :). A thing to consider, if you're planning to use lots of separate scripts, you might want to look at `require.js` or similar library, and build your system in modules for better code reuse.